# How to rewrite these url on htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i want to rewrite these URL

```
getimage.php?videoid=myquery
```

to

```
img/myquery
```

i try this ht access code but after this its show empty page

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^img/(.+)  getimage.php?videoid=$1
```

please tell me how to set it

Comment: What URL are you going to?

Comment: please read again my post

Comment: You say you want to redirect `getimage.php?videoid=myquery` to `img/myquery`, but your rule matches the other way around, so which of the two URL's are you typing in your browser's address bar?

Comment: sorry i want rewrite these url

Comment: Try to wrap your rules with `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` `</IfModule>` maybe _mod_rewrite_ is not enabled

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} videoid=(.+)
#RewriteRule getimage.php$ /img/%1? [R=301,L] #redirect
RewriteRule getimage.php$ test/%1? [L] #rewrite
```

Comment: Please research before posting answers. Guesswork doesn't help the OP.

Comment: @SameedAlam fixed,sorry

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /getimage.php\?videoid=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ img/%1? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^img/([^/.]+)/?$ getimage.php?videoid=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```